# Calculate way points order does not function google maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, salesforce, apex

I am using google maps API for calculating a route with waypoints

Sometimes route is correctly calculated but sometimes not

I take some values from Apex (this is a VisualForce Page Salesforce with Javascript)

```
          var wayptsApresMidi = [];
          var wayPointApresMidi = {!wayPointsLocationOfPCEApresMidi};

          for(var i= 0; i < wayPointApresMidi.length; i++){                 
            wayptsApresMidi.push({
              location: new google.maps.LatLng(wayPointApresMidi[i][1], wayPointApresMidi[i][0]),
              stopover: true
            });
          }

          console.log('firstLocationOfPCELatitudeApresMidi '+'{!firstLocationOfPCELatitudeApresMidi}'); 
          console.log('firstLocationOfPCELongitudeApresMidi '+'{!firstLocationOfPCELongitudeApresMidi}'); 
          console.log('lastLocationOfPCELatitudeApresMidi '+'{!lastLocationOfPCELatitudeApresMidi}'); 
          console.log('lastLocationOfPCELongitudeApresMidi '+'{!lastLocationOfPCELongitudeApresMidi}'); 

          for(var i=0; i<wayptsApresMidi.length; i++){
              console.debug('wayptsApresMidi Longitude and Latitude '+wayptsApresMidi[i].location);
          }

          directionsServiceApresMidi.route({
              origin: new google.maps.LatLng('{!firstLocationOfPCELatitudeApresMidi}', '{!firstLocationOfPCELongitudeApresMidi}'),
              destination: new google.maps.LatLng('{!lastLocationOfPCELatitudeApresMidi}','{!lastLocationOfPCELongitudeApresMidi}'),
              waypoints: wayptsApresMidi,
              optimizeWaypoints: true,
              travelMode: 'DRIVING',
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
              language: 'fr'
            }, function(response, status) {
              if (status === 'OK') {
                  console.log(response);

            for (var i = 0; i < response.routes[0].legs.length; i++) 
            {
                console.log(response.routes[0].legs[i].start_address);
                console.log(response.routes[0].legs[i].end_address);
            }
         });
```

When not functions the values returned for waypoint_order can be [4294967295, 4294967295] (The number of wayPoints is correct but values are 4294967295)

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.routes[0].legs.length; i++) 
            {
                console.log(response.routes[0].legs[i].start_address);
                console.log(response.routes[0].legs[i].end_address);
            }
```

ten times

> 38 Rue Verte, xxxx, France

firstPoint/ WAyPoints/ LastPoint have some good values

Furthermore, when the travelMode is WALKING to put travelMode DRIVING can function 
(the contrary is true -> when DRIVING is not functionned WALKING can function)

The before weeks it worked always
i don't know if it functions only sometimes because of changes in my code or if Google Maps API has modified something in the process

It can have 16 digits after dot for latitude/ longitude (Is it a problem ?)

Do you have an idea ?
Thanks,

Comment: Can I use the code you provided to reproduce the issue? No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue.

Please see the following google issue tracker.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135627404

Comment: OH This happen for me exactly !

Comment: Please could you star the issuetracker? It's at the top left.

Comment: A link to solution is good but make sure your answer provide useful notes , As well as you can use comments if you want to point to something

Comment: @Abdulrahman I would have preferred to leave a comment but I don't have the rep to do it.